# Clients and a server connection by SSH with authentication key usage

Tags: ssh, authentication

What is the way to share a server's SSH key to clients to allow them connect by SSH to that server?

In the every manual about SSH authentication a connection between clients and server through transferring a public key of client into "authorized_keys" on remote server described. But, in my case, server doesn't know about his clients, he wants to share his own key and allows to connect for trusted clients.

How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some authentication for the users.

If you don't want password, you can create keypair on server and share private part with the client (and store the public part in `authorized_keys file`), as some services does.

Generate keypair:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f rsa_key
$ # rsa_key <-- private key
$ # rsa.key.pub <-- public key
```

Comment: It seems what I need... But could you provide more details or any links? How this keypair should be generated? In my understanding, the server has to generate public and private key, share his private key to clients and store public key in his own "authorized_keys" file, right?

Comment: I modified the question how to create key pair.

Comment: @Jakue, thank you, but what about the second part of my comment? Is my understanding correct? Additionally, where clients have to store the obtained key from server? Does any special path exist (~/.ssh/)?

Comment: this depends on clients, but for openssh, standard path for rsa keys is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. But they can store it elsewhere and then add the path using `-i` switch to `ssh`, like this: `ssh -i path/to/key remote_host`

Comment: Now it's clear, i.e. server generates key "instead of" clients and then provides this key them, also stores public key inside himself. 


Just wondering, when a client wants to generate his own SSH key (e.g. to connect another remote server), will be it possible in such case? Are the multiple SSH keys supported?

Comment: Yes. The authorized_keys file can contain more keys (from there the name). Each on new line.